# If checkbox is checked display on homepage

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a checkbox option to display a certain function on either on homepage only or in all over the page,

**Checkbox**

```
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="home-only" name="mytheme_options[home-only]" value="1" checked="checked">
```

**PHP**

```
$display_in_home = mytheme_option('home-only');
if ($display_in_home == 1) { 
    echo 'Sample Text';
}
```

I'm not sure how do I include/or assign the `$display_in_home == 1` to the function

```
is_front_page()
```

in my code above

I tried something like this but no luck

```
$showin_in_home = mytheme_option('home-only');
$front = is_front_page();
if( $showin_in_home == 1 ) $filter = $front;
else  $filter = '';
if ($filter) { 
echo 'Sample Text';
}
```

Sorry If my above code looks funny, I am just new and started learning on PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for [logical operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

Try something like this:

```
if( mytheme_option('home-only') && is_front_page() )
{
    echo 'Sample text';
}
```

This may be useful for using as a shortcut: `$show_in_home = mytheme_option('home-only');`.

But, in my opinion, this is not necessary: `$filter = is_front_page()`.